# running python selenium in VS opens up powershell

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, web

I am running a python selenium in Visual Studio but every time I run it, Powershell keeps popping out and it could not call the webdriver. Could you help what could be wrong in my VS or python selenium code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                          options=options)

driver.get("https://myaccount.google.com/")
```

I am expecting the webdriver to be launch and would be redirected to the site.